# System views in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, system-views

I'm using system catalog views such as SYS.ALL_ OBJECTS, SYS.FOREIGN_KEYS etc. to get information about my database structure in MS SQL 2005.

Are there equivalent functions/views for MySQL (v. 5) servers?

Comment: I see now that MS SQL Server also supports INFORMATION_SCHEMA, but the syntax is not 100% compatible with MySQL. Catalog views are the recommended access method according to Books Online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the schema (All objects);

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S;
```

For constraints and foreign keys also;

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T;
```

For everything else check this queries;

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.CHARACTER_SETS C;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY C;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLLATIONS C;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES C;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROFILING P;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES R;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES S;  
SELECT * FROM information_schema.STATISTICS S;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_PRIVILEGES T;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TRIGGERS T;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES U;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.VIEWS V;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I haven't studied everything it contains, but there's a good deal of information in the [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html).  There's also the [show](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html) command.

Still, I don't see a single command to show all the foreign keys in there.